# How to speed up opening vim Buffer?

Tags: vim

Opening files the first time is very slow in vim. I made a `vim --startuptime start.log .vimrc`. These are the TOP4 found in `start.log`

```
2075.385  1790.067: opening buffers

2200.133  124.203: BufEnter autocommands

117.800  082.955  062.110: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc

247.013  073.089  073.089: sourcing /home/fwagner/.vim/bundle/vim-fat-finger/plugin/fat-finger.vim
```

Is there a way to speed up the buffer opening?

Comment: How many buffers are we talking about? Did you try without a vimrc?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I just opened my .vimrc (which has ~500 lines) in the example. So opening a single file/buffer is already very slow.

Comment: Could you post the content of your `~/.vimrc`? All of it.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your autocommands are grouped like this:

```
augroup EditVim
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc source $MYVIMRC
  autocmd FileType vim setlocal foldmethod=marker
augroup END
```

If your vimrc is being sourced multiple times for some reason and your autocommands are not cancelled with `autocmd!`, your BufEnter commands will be registered again and again and vim will slow to a crawl. It's one of the (many) edge cases in vim.

Check out [this chapter](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html) of [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com) by Steve Losh for more info.